# Cannot dump definition because of invalid class name ('\\Memcache')

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached

I using symfony 2 and memcache I tryed to inject it like that

```
services:
    memcache:
        class: \Memcache
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_host%, %session_port% ]]  
    session.handler.memcache:
            class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
            arguments: [@memcache]
```

but i get this error on any webpage i visit on my project

```
RuntimeException in PhpDumper.php line 1461: Cannot dump definition because of invalid class name ('\\Memcache')
```

I tried to remove "\" like that

```
memcache:
    class: Memcache
```

and I get this error

```
Attempted to load class "Memcache" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Comment: Do you have Memcached installed?

Comment: Do you have the php_memcache extension activated in PHP?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i installed it using this command sudo apt-get install php-memcache -y 

i using symfony2 i have extension="memcache.so" on php.ini inside symfony

Answer (score 0):

It's actually recommended using `Memcached` instead of `Memcache` extension.
Try to run:

```
apt-get install -y memcached php-memcached
```

And in your config use:

```
services:
    memcache:
        class: Memcached
```

If you are using apache you might also need to run:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i get 

ClassNotFoundException in Memcached.php line 7: Attempted to load class "Memcached" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?